# Browser fetch works, but AngularJS $http service has CORS error

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, fetch

I would like to understand why the AngularJS **$http** service doesn't work and the **fetch** API works.

Below is the AngularJS code:

```
const $http = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http')
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://192.168.1.126:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/datasources/',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
  }
})
```

This gives me this error:

> angular.js:12845 OPTIONS http://192.168.1.126:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/datasources/ 403 ()
>       Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

The weird part is that this:

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.126:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/datasources/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
    }
}).then((r) => r.json()).then(console.log)
```

Gives me the correct response

I know this could be a CORS error, but i've added the CORS filter on my tomcat so everything should work (and fetch works).
Is this a bug in fetch or $http?

Answer (score 2):

While i was writing this question i found the answer:

On my AngularJS app, there was a **config file** that was setting this:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
```

And this (along with other headers), **makes the request a preflighted** one, as peer the [CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests):

> [...] Apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (for
>   example, **Connection**, **User-Agent**, [or any of the other header with a
>   name defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden header name”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)), the
>   request includes any headers other than those which the Fetch spec
>   defines as being a “CORS-safelisted request-header”, which are the
>   following:
>
> - Accept Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type (but note the additional requirements below)
> - Last-Event-ID
> - DPR
> - Save-Data
> - Viewport-Width
> - Width

So the fetch API worked because it wasn't setting that (`If-Modified-Since`) header, and the $http service was.

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Did you change the config file? Or do I have to use fetch() instead of $http?

Comment: @Ahmet sorry, I don't recall my solution, but I'm pretty sure that I was just curious about it, so I didn't fixed. You probably will need to either remove the header or configure CORs  to accept another origin on your server